# Source of Windows 10 update files

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

In Windows 10, I set "Get updates from Microsoft, and get updates from and send updates to" PCs on my local network.
On the local PC, is it possible to look up the IP that packages are being downloaded from / have been downloaded from?
In corporate environments, I know that I can intentionally set up WSUS, but this is for a local PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you can catch Windows Delivery Optimization Service in the act of transferring an update, sure, you can find out its IP address using NetStat or NetStat-like utilities.

Microsoft offers one such utility called [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview). Of course, you probably need to use it in conjunction with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) to find out the process ID of under which Windows Delivery Optimization Service works. Another suggestion is using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which is the equivalent of both Process Explorer and TCPView combined.